# AWS Fail to set timeout on ALB, Service, Task

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-fargate

I've got an unexpected error, I guess it's about timeout.
Task takes time quite long. generally less than 1minute. There is no problem when it fininsh before 1 minute. But sometimes task takes more than 1 minute. Error occurs when it takes more than 1minute. Please see below.

```
[ec2-user@ip-000-00-0-00 ~]$ curl --location --request POST 'userid.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com:port/service' -d "video.mp4" -o output.json -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 172.31.74.35:5000...
* Connected to loadbalancer.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com (000.00.00.00) port 0000 (#0)
> POST /service HTTP/1.1
> Host: userid.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com:port
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 37
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [37 bytes data]
100    37    0     0    0    37      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:59 --:--:--     0* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2022 01:45:23 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Python/3.7 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0
< 
100    37    0     0    0    37      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:00 --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host loadbalancer.ap-northeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com left intactm left intact
```

With curl verbose option, I get 500 Internal Server Error at 0:00:59. How can I finish my task which takes more than 1minutes?

I've tried

- increasing Health check grace period for **ECS Service**
- increasing idle timeout of **Load Balancer**
- increasing timeout and interval of **Target group**
- curl options (like keep-alive, max-time)

My EC2 Instance

- type : t2.micro
- Amazon Linux

My Service

- Service type : REPLICA
- Launch type : FARGATE

My task in service

- Network mode : awsvpc
- Compatibilities : EC2, FARGATE
- Requries compatibilities : FARGATE
- EFS mounted
- Docker

Appreciate,

Comment: If it's related to timeout you can use `--max-time 120`(2 minutes) option.

Comment: I've tried curl option `--max-time 120`, It doesn't work.